# HTTP GET method Error

Tags: apex, visualforce, callout, httppost

I'm trying to retrieve my VisualForce Page that I have already Render as a PDF using my Apex Class so I can store the page as a PDF inside the document folder.

But, I keep on having an Error when testing the Code. Can someone help me out with this?

---

### Debug Log Error

[image]

---

### Developer Console Error

[image]

---

### Apex Class Code

```
public class testFBInt {

     public void exInt() {
        //converting to base64
        String base64Data = '';
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('https://c.ap4.visual.force.com/apex/Dashboard_PDF'); 
        req.setMethod('GET');
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
        Blob image = res.getBodyAsBlob();
        base64Data =  EncodingUtil.base64Encode(image);
        System.debug('@@ base64 @@' + base64Data );

    //inserting into documents
    Document doc = new Document();
    doc.Name = 'SF_Dashboard.pdf';
    doc.body = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(base64Data);
    doc.folderId = '00l900000027wOx'; //your folder id
    doc.IsPublic = true;
    doc.Description = 'Salesforce Dashboard Report -' + String.valueOf(date.today().format());

    insert doc;
    System.debug('@@ doc @@' +doc);

    //retrieving the file details
    List<Document> lstfbdoc = [Select Id, Name, Description, Type FROM Document Where Name =: 'SF_Dashboard.pdf'];
    }
}
```

---

### VisualForce Page Code

```
<apex:page name="Custom_Dash_Board" renderAs="PDF" showHeader="true" sidebar="false" title="Custom DashBoard">
<html>

<h2 >Sales</h2> 
<img src="https://ap4.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ChartServer?rsid=0FL6F000002dBX3&ruid=0056F00000746E0&did=01Z6F000001DwLb&s=7&fs=10&tfg=12&tfs=-16777063&explode=0&c=gauge&cs=0&title=Closed+Sales+To+Date&eh=no&compo=yes&fg=-16777216&bg1=-1&bg2=-3355393&bgdir=2&dl1=Account+Name&dl2=&l=2&sax=yes&Yman=no&nc=0&actUrl=%2F00O6F00000Aug7k%3Fdbw%3D1&sd=1&scv=no&sct=yes&spt=no&bd=yes&cu=SGD&ab=X&u=0&vt=0&ab2=Y&u2=1&vt2=2&vl0=Sum+of+Amount&spoc=no&topn=no&gm=0.0&gc0=-6750208&gm0=500000.0&gc1=-13210&gm1=1000000.0&gc2=-16738048&gm2=1500000.0&sona=0&refreshts=1491383581000" />

<h2 >Historical Snapshot</h2>
<img src="https://ap4.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ChartServer?rsid=0FL6F000002dBXF&ruid=0056F00000746E0&did=01Z6F000001DwLb&s=6&fs=10&tfg=12&tfs=-16777063&explode=0&c=column&cs=2&title=&eh=no&compo=yes&fg=-16777216&bg1=-1&bg2=-3355393&bgdir=2&dl1=As+of+Date&dl2=Historical+Stage&l=2&sax=yes&Yman=no&nc=0&actUrl=%2F00O6F00000Aug7w%3Fdbw%3D1&sd=1&scv=no&sct=no&spt=no&bd=yes&cu=SGD&ab=X&u=0&vt=0&ab2=Y&u2=0&vt2=2&vl0=Sum+of+Historical+Amount&spoc=no&topn=no&gc0=-4041644&gc1=-4013484&gc2=-11222444&sona=0&refreshts=1491458466000" />

</html>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error's coming from here:

```
base64Data =  EncodingUtil.base64Encode(image);
```

In your HttpCalloutMock implementation, you need to remember to call setBodyAsBlob, since you're calling getBodyAsBlob.

```
class FBIntCalloutMock implements HttpCalloutMock {
  public HttpResponse respond(HttpRequest req) {
    HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
    res.setBodyAsBlob(Blob.valueOf('sample image content'));
    return res;
  }
}
```

You need to remember that HttpCalloutMock is not a *real* callout, and so is only as explicitly loaded with information as you specify in the implementation.

Comment: I tried editing it to this


        `String base64Data = '';
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setBodyAsBlob(Blob.valueOf('https://c.ap4.visual.force.com/apex/Dashboard_PDF'));
    //req.setEndpoint('https://c.ap4.visual.force.com/apex/Dashboard_PDF'); 
    //req.setMethod('GET');
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
    Blob image = res.getBodyAsBlob();
    base64Data =  EncodingUtil.base64Encode(image);`


But it still doesn't work

Comment: @LukeAu Your code was fine--your unit test is what needs to be updated.

Comment: Thanks the error is solve but now the file is not being upload to the folder